# Next js custom server using express to route

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js

hello i am some where between beginner and intermediate in nextjs. in my project i am using custom server using express

////server.js

```
const { query } = require('express');
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  server.get('/', function (req, res) {
    // res.write(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<myPage />))
    return app.render(req, res, '/index', query);
  });

  // server.all('*', (req, res) => {
  //   return handle(req, res);
  // });

  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

and i disable file-system based router

////next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  useFileSystemPublicRoutes: false,
};
```

i what to render pages in my pages folder of nextjs like in normal express how can i do .Thanks for your response

Comment: I assume you want to use nextJS + express server as backend?

Comment: yes i what to use next js as a template engine @SomeoneSpecial

Comment: you probably wouldn't want to disable useFileSystemPublicRoutes. You may just want to manually ensure your path does not overlap each other. If you disable useFileSystemPublicRoutes, you may as well just use CRA + express without using nextjs

Comment: I tried with out disable file base routing for my project but that does not work

Comment: is there is anyway to archive using nextjs pages to render for express @SomeoneSpecial

Comment: i used to use this example and i did not disable useFileSystemPublicRoutes - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/custom-server-express

Comment: were you ever able to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to do that by adding

```js
    server.all("*", (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res);
    });
```

because when I visit localhost:3000 I see it requests other modules like web pack.js and our express didn't handle that so we need. nextJS to handle the rest of the assets

so it should look. like this

```js
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 1234;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express();

    server.get("/", (req, res) => {
        return app.render(req, res, "/", req.query);
    });

    server.get("/a", (req, res) => {
        return app.render(req, res, "/a", req.query);
    });

    server.get("/b", (req, res) => {
        return app.render(req, res, "/b", req.query);
    });

    // server.get("/", (req, res) => {
    //  return app.render(req, res, "/", req.query);
    // });

    server.all("*", (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res);
    });

    server.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
});
```